# audiocontext Samplerate returning null after being read 8 times

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have made a function to produce a drum sound how ever after being called 4 times it stops working with the error:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'audioCtx.sampleRate')
>   Showing in the console.

What's wrong with this function?
My code is:

```
drum = function(){
    var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    var frameCount = audioCtx.sampleRate/20
    var myArrayBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(1, frameCount, audioCtx.sampleRate);
    var nowBuffering = myArrayBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    for (var i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
        nowBuffering[i] =Math.sin(i**(1/1.8)/4)
    }

    var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = myArrayBuffer; source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    source.start();
}
```

Comment: iOS safari mobile

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `audioCtx` assignment should be moved outside of `drum()`, as it will get called every time, eventually throwing an exception since you can't create more than 6 audio contexts in a document.

Comment: I didn’t know about the limit of 6 per document! Thanks for the heads up.  Do you know where this is documented?  Is the limit part of a spec, or just the current webkit implementation?

Comment: @Zearin Good question. It's currently an undocumented limitation of Chromium. Firefox and Safari seem to allow more. But you really shouldn't need more than 1 per app.

Answer (score -1):

In fact reusing one instance of AudioContext is not good solution as it's potential memory leak.

Such long-living AudioContext instance is killed by Safari when browser goes idle (when you switch to another iOS app). Once the Safari is opened again AudioContext instance is no longer available.

**Proper solution is to create new context each time and close it when it's no longer needed.**

With such approach no browser limit on AudioContext is applied.

```js
const drum = () => {
  const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)()
  // your stuff here…

  // Return cleanup function and call it when needed
  return () => {
    // Cleanup to prevent memory leaks
    audioCtx
      .close()
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('Closing AudioContext failed')
      })
  }
}
```